# SQLAlchemy NOT exists on subselect?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to replicate this raw sql into proper sqlalchemy implementation but after a lot of tries I can't find a proper way to do it:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM images i
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT image_id
    FROM events e
    WHERE e.image_id=i.id AND e.chat_id=:chat_id)
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 1
```

Closest I got is:

```
session.query(Image).filter(and_(Event.image_id == Image.id, Event.chat_id == chat_id)).order_by(func.random()).limit(1)
```

But I cant seem to find how to put the NOT EXISTS clause.

Can anyone lend a helping hand?

Thanks!

Comment: What are some of these attempts that didn't work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're querying the `FROM images` table, but the `WHERE` clause is a subquery, not `e.image_id=i.id AND e.chat_id=:chat_id` (these filters are for `events` instead). So, the correct query is of the form

```
session.query(Image).filter(subquery).order_by(func.random()).limit(1)
```

The way to form an `EXISTS` subquery is with the `.exists()` method, so to get `NOT EXISTS` just use the `~` operator:

```
subquery = ~session.query(Event).filter(Event.image_id == Image.id, Event.chat_id == chat_id).exists()
```

Note that the emitted query is not identical to your original (e.g. it uses `EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)`), but it's functionally the same.

Comment: that's perfect! thank you very much, you're a life saver.